# Segmentation fault while running some ubuntu specific apps like nautilus, unity-control-center, etc

Tags: unity, nautilus, themes, segmentation-fault, unity-control-center

running nautilus from the terminal the following errors are returned:

```
compro@Inspiron-3543:~/.learn_unix$ nautilus &
[1] 7326
compro@Inspiron-3543:~/.learn_unix$ 
(nautilus:7326): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-dark.css:18:1: '/*' in comment block
Initializing nautilus-open-terminal extension
^C
[1]+  Segmentation fault      nautilus
```

info about my os [uname -a]:

```
Linux Inspiron-3543 3.13.0-36-generic #63+hwe3-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 18 15:53:49 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

the problem occurred from the time when i changed the theme from Ambiance to Radiance and the unity-control-center crashed. from then and there i am having  problems like:
1) when i click on File/Edit/etc. menus in gterminal it crashes
2) when i press shift/alt/ctrl keys in nautilus it crashes
and many other similar issues.

I had recently upgraded it to 14.04 to solve the problem. But still the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did it. I only had to move all my pictures, videos, music, etc. to another newly made account's home directory and then everything was reset. The main thing was that the system messed with my themes configuration files so I removed all my files from my previous account.